# Reload child with timer

Tags: reactjs

I have a save prompt that appears when various parent components have data submitted to the server. The save prompt is a very simple component:

```
export class PromptComponent extends React.Component<{}, {}> {
constructor(props: any) {
    super(props)
}
public render(): JSX.Element {
    return (
        <div>
            {this.props.showAlert ? (
                <div id='alert-prompt'>
                    <span>{this.props.children}</span>
                </div>
            ) : null}
        </div>
    )
}
}
```

My issue is that in the parent, my showAlert prop is a reflection of the parent state doing the following function:

```
    const closeAlert = () => {
        const closeModal = () => this.setState({
            showAlert: false,
        })
        setTimeout(closeModal, 1000)
    }
    this.setState(
        {
            showAlert: true,
        },
        () => closeAlert()
    )
```

So this gets redundant if I have to put this code in every parent, and have them keep track of the state of the alert. Is there a more efficient way to do this with less code? Ideally I would like to move the timer-dependent state into the actual alert component itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a callback (`useCallback` props) function to be used within the child component.

Check [this example](https://6h09b.codesandbox.io/):

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Flexbox>
        <PromptComponent
          useCallback={callback => {
            setTimeout(() => {
              callback();
            }, 1000);
          }}
        >
          Hello
        </PromptComponent>
      </Flexbox>
    );
  }
}
```

Move the `show` state to your child component and use the callback:

```js
export default class PromptComponent extends React.Component {
  state = {
    show: true
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.showAlert(() => this.setState({ show: false }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.show && (
          <div id="alert-prompt">
            <span>{this.props.children}</span>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

This way you decouple the state from your parent component, also your callback is a generic one, so in future, you can change it to `setInterval` or anything else.

[image: Edit Q-56823769-ShowComponentTimeout]

Comment: Wow this is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!